# Disabled specific options from select with ngOptions

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a select dropdown, like this:

`<select ng-model="expressionClause.field" ng-options="o.fullPropertyName as o.displayName for o in model.discountExpressionProperties" ng-change="expressionClause.value = ''" required></select>`

Is it possible to add a 'disabled' attribute on two of those rendered options without modifying the controller? And without using ngRepeat instead of ngOptions?

I've tried this:

`<select ng-model="expressionClause.field" ng-options="o.fullPropertyName as o.displayName disable when o.displayName == 'Product ID' for o in model.discountExpressionProperties" ng-change="expressionClause.value = ''" required></select>`

But I don't think I am using it correctly as I get a syntax error:

`Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'disable' is an unexpected token at column 15 of the expression [o.displayName disable when o.displayName == 'Product ID'] starting at [disable when o.displayName == 'Product ID'].`

LE: AngularJS v1.3.20

Comment: Which version of Angular do you have? This is a relatively new functionality from what I could find.

Comment: Good question @henrikmerlander. v1.3.20

Comment: I guess the `disable when` bit only works if later or equal to 1.4.7.. pff.

Answer (score 1):

Release notes for Angular 1.4.0-beta.5:

```
"ngOptions: add support for disabling an option (da9eac86, #638, #11017)"
```

Try updating your Angular version.